# use case statement along with partition by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data as below

[image]

if there is a customer 1, and he has multiple rows of comments. Even if any one of the comments has the keyword "sania", I want that customer to be flagged as '0'. else mark as '1'.

Comment: `CASE` and `PARTITION BY` have no relation; `PARTITION BY` part of the `OVER` clause when windowing aggregate functions, a `CASE` is an **expression** that returns a scalar value.

Comment: Also what does any of this have to do with what you have tagged? Why have you tagged [[tag:python]]? Are you actually looking for a solution in Python, not (T-)SQL? Images of data do not help us help you either. What have you tried to solve your problem? Why didn't it work?

Comment: I think you want something like: `Flag = MIN(CASE WHEN comments LIKE '%sania%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER(PARTITION BY Customer)`,

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
select
       customer 
     , comments
     , min(case when comments='sania' then 0 else 1 end) 
       over (partition by customer) as new_flag
from Tbl
```